# Does NHibernate need no device like Entity Framework's DbSet<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, dbset, isession

From what I have gathered. the `DbSet` is a typed entity cache, and on Save, a `DbContext` polls all `DbSets` for entities in need of persistence. In NHibernate, the caching and change detection for all entity types are combined in an `ISession` instance.

So, to convert very simple EF code to NH code, I can do away with the `DbSet` and just perform all operations straight on the session?

Comment: ISession is the complete answer

Answer (score 3):

The only strongly-typed way to query entities in EF is using Linq. So each entity type has its own property of type `DbSet<T>` in the data context which implements `IQueryable<T>`.

In NHibernate, there are multiple query APIs (LINQ, QueryOver, Criteria [non-generic]) available and users are expected to use the ISession dynamically.

So instead of `context.Companies.ToList()` you can perform `session.Query<Company>().ToList()`, `session.QueryOver<Company>().List()` or `session.Criteria(typeof(Company)).List()`.

The nice part about NHibernate is everything in that API is an interface, so there is no mocking involved unlike unit testing `DbSet<T>` instances.

Comment: I think I'll just build a little `NhSet<T>` shim, that passes all calls such as `Add`, straight to the session. There are too many `DbSet` variables lying around.